# Pass data from second VC to first VC and also show in textfield Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm getting data from second VC to first VC using protocol or delegates, Data is receiving in first VC but the problem is that Data is not showing in Textfield. Here is my Complete Code for understanding. Any Effort is appreciated.

FirstVC class

```
import UIKit

class firstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MyProtocol {

var valueSentFromSecondViewController               : String?
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField                      : UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func myTextFieldACTIONWhenEditingDidBegin(_ sender: Any) {
    myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController

    secondVC.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}

func setResultsAfterEvaluation(valueSent: String) {
    self.valueSentFromSecondViewController = valueSent
    print(valueSentFromSecondViewController!) // Ahtazaz(DATA showing here)
    myTextField.text = valueSentFromSecondViewController //This's the problem, Why not showing here in this this TextField
}
}
```

Now, SecondVC Class

```
import UIKit

protocol MyProtocol {
func setResultsAfterEvaluation(valueSent: String)

}

class secondViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate            :   MyProtocol?
var sentValue           :   String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
    let firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)

    sentValue = "Ahtazaz"
    delegate?.setResultsAfterEvaluation(valueSent: sentValue!)
}

}
```

Comment: can you show the complete class

Comment: add your class code or just check the connection of `propertyLocation ` Is present or removed.

Comment: @RoshanSinghBishat if connection removed it will  show error  as Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Delegate value is on main thread ? If not try adding DispatchQueue.main.sync block and check. UI ops should be done main thread.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, I updated my Question, please see.

Comment: It seems you are using StoryBoards, if so, another approach is to use unwindSegues and set data back onto the first VC, like you do when you go from first VC to the second VC. This will avoid some interface/protocol segregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing SecondVC. Then in SecondVC you are pushing again FirstVC. 
I think this is where you are making mistake.

```
let firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
```

You are creating a new instance of FirstVC. Then you push it which is wrong. Call your delegate and then Pop back to previous(FirstVC) controller

Try this code in your button action

```
@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
sentValue = "Ahtazaz"
delegate?.setResultsAfterEvaluation(valueSent: sentValue!)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This should be the correct approach rather than pushing the controller again.

Comment: Thankyou so much, And At last i worked acording to your Answer and it worked for me. Thankyou so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The steps are Simple to use `Delegates` for passing the data to previous VC

**Second VC:**

At the top of VC declare the protocol as follows:

```
protocol MenuListingDelegate {
func callBackOfMenuSelected(arrSelectedCategory:[Int],isFromWhichPopup:Int)
```

}

Then inside that define the `variable` like this

```
var delegate:MenuListingDelegate?
```

And then provide the data to the delegate like this. In my case i provide that on click of *`button`* before pop View Controller

```
self.delegate?.callBackOfMenuSelected(strToPass: "Hello")
```

Now in First VC:

At the top define the Delegate method like this:

```
class DayDetailVC: UIViewController,MenuListingDelegate {}
```

And fetch the Data like this

```
  //MARK:- Menu Listing Delegate

    func callBackOfMenuSelected(strToPass: String) {
     print(strToPass)

    }
```

> **Note:-** Do not forget to declare the delegate of the secondVC where we use this. `secondVC.delegate = self`.

### Edit Check the following cases

Case 1:- Check the outlets of the `myTextField` i guess the issue is there. If everything is correct remove the Outlet and the set that again

Case 2:- Still if doesnt work then try setting like this

```
func setResultsAfterEvaluation(valueSent: String) {
myTextField.text = "\(valueSent)" 
}
```

Hope this helps.

### Edit 2

I have seen you have used pushViewController in the following lines:
So you can simply use the following line of code to pass the data to **firstVC**

In **SecondVC** add following Code:

```
 let firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as! firstViewController
firstVC.valueSentFromSecondViewController = "Hello World"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
```

Now in **FirstVC**

Use like in `viewDidLoad()` or anywhere you want

```
print(valueSentFromSecondViewController) //Hello World
```

Cheers it Done.

Choose the way you want.

> Note:- But i will suggest you to use `popViewController` instead of
>   `pushViewController` when returning back from **SecondVC -> FirstVC**. Rest depends upon your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: AS per question data is coming from SecondVC. The main concern is that is not showing.

Comment: So i have shown all the steps to pass data from SecondVC to first VC.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer but my problem has not fulfill, I updated my Question, please see.

Comment: Are you sure you want to send using delegate only.? I mean i have seen in your code, you have used push so you can another way to pass data. May i suggest you that.?

Comment: @Ahtazazkhan Edited the Answer for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Again the problem is not solve. I'm using push just for navigating the VC.  Need help. What's the problem. Even textField outlet working fine.

Comment: Have You tried All the steps I have Mentioned? I have described the delegate method as well as direct method Both in detail. Double Check the steps and re do all the stuffs please